# How to seperate the finger touch feature in one layout and one activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

If my main layout consists of two linear layout like following:

**res/layout/main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <TextView
          android:text="red"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#aa0000"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <TextView
          android:text="blue"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#0000aa"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="yellow"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#aaaa00"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="row one"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row two"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row three"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity class looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I would like to implement a feature that the upper linear layout(which contain colors) can move content with finger touch, that's I have to implement `OnTouchListener` , but for the lower linear layout(which contains several TextView) I do not want to have finger touch feature.

Since they are in one xml layout file, and I have one Java class (MainActivity.java), how can I separate them with half of the layout has finger touch feature, but implement `onTouchListener` in the whole main activity class?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible . you have to set ontouchlistener for that particular view . so only that view respond to touch event.

Comment: That's what I am asking about, how to set ontouchlistener for that particular view as they are defined all in one xml file and referenced in on activity java class.

Comment: Please give android:id to linearlayout or any other view on which you want touch listener then set touch listener on that view